# Do I want Enlist=False in my SQL connection string?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, transactions

We have a large website built with ASP.NET and SQL Server 2008, and there are a few connection issues that might (according to other StackOverflow questions, and elsewhere) be solved by adding `Enlist=False` to the connection string, to override the default value of `True`.

I read about distributed transactions, and I don't think we use them, but I still feel unsure of making this change on our live server. And maybe it would make no difference! My underlying question, is:

**Do I want to add `Enlist=False` to my connection string when we do not use any transactions in ASP.NET code?**

There is talk of adding transactions to one or two our SQL stored procedures in the near future - simple `BEGIN TRAN` and `COMMIT TRAN` sort of stuff - but certainly never in ASP.NET will we have transactions. (We do not use DAAB either.)

Comment: Are you trying to use SO as a substitute for having a test environment? Because this is the sort of thing you do need to test with *your* systems and *your* data. Or is the word of a random stranger on the internet good enough to convince you to make a change in production?

Comment: It's best to avoid distributed transactions unless the application specifically needs them, so enlist=false will ensure DTs are not used inadvertently. If you know you app doesn't need or want DTs, enlist=false is appropriate. The risk of this change is only if your app actually does rely on DTs and relies on auto enlistment.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, It seems I haven't explained things very well. I do have a test environment, but I cannot recreate the bug as it is intermittent and seems to need around 5000 website visitors to set it off. What I am asking for here is greater understanding of what this setting does, because I am not sure if it even applies to my situation. Fortified with that, I can research further. (Also, the concept of SO 'rep' is a good way to indicate the trustworthiness of random strangers.)

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand your question and would like to share some experience.

**Part 1**

I am distributing an ASP.NET application where I fundamentally do not need own transactions. The application is running on private laptops as well inside of enterprise frameworks, on virtual servers with distributed services.

About two years ago, I encountered a situation where I set `Enlist=False` in the `web.config` to avoid an exception.

This worked well all the time - so the first part of my answer is, if you do not need transactions, distributed transactions or else, you won't do harm if you add `Enlist=False`.

**Part 2**

In the meantime, I've added a lot of import function. On an import, several hundred new database records may be created. Here, it is crucial for me to rollback everything if something goes wrong. As I cannot create sophisticated SQL rollback (i.e. creating single SQL rollback-commands while importing), I am forced to use transactions.

As the import is rather complex, I ended up having mixed code:

- Some code is using DbContext: `MyEntities.Add(xx)`, ... , `dbContext.SaveChanges()`
- Some code has SQL, using `SqlCommand`.

Therefore, I had to combine those actions within some transaction frame - turned out that [`TransactionScope`](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/690136/All-About-TransactionScope) is the right and wonderful thing. But, it took me some time to understand that `TransactionScope` only works if `Enlist=False` *is not set*. The nested actions simply do not enlist to the transaction frame otherwise, and avoiding `Complete()` in order to rollback has no impact.

Now I continue to use `Enlist=False` as my application standard, but for the import, I create a temporary `DbContext` with a modified connection string. You get the idea:

```
...
connectionString = Regex.Replace(originalString, @"\s*;\s*Enlist\s*=\s*False\s*", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
...
```

This blends in, because I offer the possibility of choosing between databases and I must get the connection string dynamically anyway. This works fine, and I have full control about what is happing where.

The second part of my answer is therefore, you can remove `Enlist=False` occasionally, if you later run into problems.

I am building with the target ASP.NET framework version 4.5.